# Как узнать длину области памяти на которую указывает указатель?

Tags: c, указатели, память

Допустим, у меня есть указатель на `unsigned int`. Я могу написать, например:

```
  unsigned int * intPtr = malloc(sizeof(unsigned int)*5);
  for (int i= 0; i< 5; i++) intPtr[i]= i+1;
```

Заполнил в цикле для примера. Как мне узнать размер этой области памяти? Понятно, что сейчас эта область занимает 20 байт, но я хочу получить ее размер именно программно. То есть, если у меня есть указатель на `char`, я могу узнать его длину так:

```
 unsigned char * chPtr = "exeple string\n";
 unsigned int chPtrSize = strlen(chPtr);
```

Как нибудь можно в байтах узнать текущий размер выделенной памяти?

Comment: нет ...........

Comment: Каждые пару дней спрашивают про это

Comment: **Никак**. Разве что непереносимо - раскопать, как конкретно работает конкретный менеджер памяти, что и где хранит... Кстати, `strlen` возвращает не длину выделенной памяти, а количество символов, предшествующих нулевому - а это совсем другое... `unsigned char * chPtr = "exeple string\n\0\0\0\0\0Ну и какой результат strlen теперь?";`

Comment: @Harry а вы часто признак конца строки в середине строки встречаете? Как первый \0 встретит, так и вернет длину строки. Оно и понятно

Comment: Указатель, по определению — это адрес ячейки памяти. Всё. Никаких длин и размеров.

Comment: В общем случае никак. В некоторых других случаях можно. Диспечер памяти хранит размер выделеного участка, как правило в области [ptr-16... ptr-1]. Для LocalAlloc можно LocalSize узнать длинну участка. Для malloc - возможно в некоторых версиях тоже можно. Думаю проанализировав область памяти до ptr, для разных выделеных кусков - вы можете самостоятельно найти байты, отвечающие за размер участка, но из минусов - теряете кросс-платформенность.

Comment: [malloc_usable_size](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc_usable_size.3.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можно получить, но не сколько запрашивали, а сколько выделила библиотека.

[malloc_usable_size(3) — Linux manual page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc_usable_size.3.html)

Комментарий из `/usr/include/malloc.h`

```
/* Report the number of usable allocated bytes associated with allocated
   chunk __ptr. */
extern size_t malloc_usable_size (void *__ptr) __THROW;
```

Пример программы

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <malloc.h>

int
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  void *p = malloc(100);
  size_t s = malloc_usable_size(p);
  
  printf("%p %zd\n", p, s);
  
  return puts("End") == EOF;
}
```

Транслируем и запускаем

```
avp@avp-xubu2:~/hashcode$ gcc t-malloc_usable_size.c 
avp@avp-xubu2:~/hashcode$ ./a.out
0x55f36e329260 104
End
avp@avp-xubu2:~/hashcode$
```

В windows есть аналогичная функция с названием [_msize](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/msize?view=vs-2019)

Answer (score 0):

Узнать размер можно, если вы сами напишите свой диспетчер памяти. В плюсах есть команда `delete [ ] ptr ;`. Она хранит размер массива где-то рядом, но не говорит где. Вы можете сами написать такое. Побочные эффекты это занимание лишних восемь байт памяти.

```
// gcc-9 -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -std=c11 memsize.c -o memsize
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

typedef struct s_malloc t_malloc ;

struct s_malloc {
  size_t size ;
  uint8_t memory [ ] ;
} ;

void * mem_alloc ( size_t const n ) {
  t_malloc * const tm = malloc ( sizeof ( t_malloc ) + n ) ;
  if ( tm ) {
    tm -> size = n ;
    return & tm -> memory ; }
  return 0 ; }

size_t mem_size ( void * const ptr ) {
  return * ( size_t * ) ( ( ( uint8_t * ) ptr )
    - offsetof  ( t_malloc  , memory  )
    + offsetof  ( t_malloc  , size  ) ) ; }

void mem_free ( void * const ptr ) {
  free ( ( ( uint8_t * ) ptr ) - offsetof  ( t_malloc  , memory  ) ) ; }

int main ( ) {
  char * str = mem_alloc ( 10 ) ;
  str [ 0 ] = '\00' ;
  printf ( u8"размер памяти = %zu\n" , mem_size ( str ) ) ;
  mem_free ( str ) ; }
```